# Converting an array of objects into a single object by one of the keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert an array that contains objects into a single object where the key is "page" and the value is "has_access". So I could access it later with has_access.about for example.

Is there a single one line of code that could achieve this?

I tried this but it is giving me back the original array.

```
var myData = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    return data[key];
})
```

Here is the source array that I would like to convert

```
[
    {
        "id": 215,
        "page": "home",
        "has_access": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 216,
        "page": "about",
        "has_access": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 217,
        "page": "profile",
        "has_access": 1,
    }
]
```

**Desired result:**

```
has_access: {
    home: 1
    about: 0
    profile: 1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the resultant object using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
    {"id": 215, "page": "home", "has_access": 1},
    {"id": 216, "page": "about", "has_access": 0},
    {"id": 217, "page": "profile", "has_access": 1}
];

const has_access = data.reduce((r, c) => (r[c.page] = c.has_access, r), {});

console.log(has_access);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the object and use `Object.assign` to update the accumulator,

```js
var data = [{"id":215,"page":"home","has_access":1},{"id":216,"page":"about","has_access":0},{"id":217,"page":"profile","has_access":1}];
var result = data.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.page]: v.has_access}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the `reduce()` method, via the following:

```js
const array = [
    {
        "id": 215,
        "page": "home",
        "has_access": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 216,
        "page": "about",
        "has_access": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 217,
        "page": "profile",
        "has_access": 1,
    }
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, i) => ({ ...acc, [ i.page ] : i.has_access }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy - specify the key and the value, then use `map` and `reduce`:

```js
const a = [{
    "id": 215,
    "page": "home",
    "has_access": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 216,
    "page": "about",
    "has_access": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 217,
    "page": "profile",
    "has_access": 1
  }
];

const value = "has_access";
const key = "page";

const res = {
  [value]: a.map(o => [o[key], o[value]]).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: v }), {})
}

console.log(res);
```